# Compare two string and return the unmatched value using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need some help on how to write the code for this scenario.

if I have two strings. For example,

```
var string1 = "string";
var string2 = "string 2";
```

Based on the strings, I want to compare both and return the unmatched value. So the output should be 2 in this situation because both variable contain "string"

Hope anyone can help me on this

Comment: `string2.replace(string1, '')`…?

Comment: What about `string2 = "string 2 string"`? Or `string1 = "string foo", string2 = "string bar foo"`? What should be the output of those? We need a bit more detail.

Comment: okay. I tried this way. It working haha why I couldn't think trying this way.  Blaming my brain :') BTW Thank you so much

Comment: @Ivar my situation is always string2 will have extra words than stringq on the back and will not repeat the same words again like `string 2 = "string 2 string"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use split method for this.

```
const var = "string"
const var2 = "string 2"
const differences = var2.split(var)
console.log(differences)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code snippet.**

```
const A = "The quick brown fox"

const B = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."

const diff = (diffMe, diffBy) => diffMe.split(diffBy).join('')

const C = diff(B, A)

console.log(C) // jumps over the lazy dog.
```